# Failed to show simulator on build server

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I am unable to build and also failed to show simulator in mac book. My pc is paired successfully My Mac Server log is

[12-Sep-2014 12:05:00] Request handled in 3.344ms

Attempting to show the simulator. You will be notified when done.

Failed to show simulator on build server.

[12-Sep-2014 12:05:03] Handling with command: [ChangeActiveApplication: CommmandUrl=ChangeActiveApplication] (11)

[12-Sep-2014 12:05:03] Attempting to acquire command execution lock, timeout set to 00:10:00

[12-Sep-2014 12:05:03] Command [ChangeActiveApplication: CommmandUrl=ChangeActiveApplication] finished (11)

[12-Sep-2014 12:05:03] Request handled in 2.934ms

[12-Sep-2014 12:05:05] Request handled in 3.461ms

[12-Sep-2014 12:05:10] Request handled in 2.873ms

Comment: Can you run same project on Mac in xamarin studio using Simulator?

Comment: Yes I am running same project on mac using Xamarin Studion It will works fine on Mac

When I runs this from Windows using Visual Studio 2013 It will gives above the error.

**One thing when I am running from Windows I will Quit the Xamarin Studio from Mac and just run Xamarin Build host